# Json length is always undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to iterate simple json array, but it always return the length of the array is **undefined**.

```
var chatmessage = {};
...................
...................
socket.on('listmessage', function(mesg){ 
chatmessage={"message":"Hello", "to":"sjdfjhsdf"};
});

socket.on('private', function(mesg){ 
console.log(chatmessage.length+' - '+chatmessage.message +' - '+ chatmessage.to);
});
```

when private event get trigger it returns

```
undefined - Hello - sjdfjhsdf
```

I think it consider **length** key word as a json array key like **{"length":40}**.

I have tried **Object.keys(chatmessage).length** but it returns the total number key value(**2**) but I have only one record.

What is the right way to iterate json in node js

Comment: `chatmessage` is an Object, not an Array. Objects don't have built-in `length`.

Comment: Object _does_ not have `length` property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to iterate simple json array

Two issues there:

1. That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. It's a JavaScript object initializer.
2. It doesn't define an array, it defines an *object*.

Objects don't have a `length` property. If you want your `chatmessage` to say how many properties it has, you'll have to add a third property explicitly (which then raises the question of whether the value should be 2 or 3 :-) ). Or alternately, you could make it an array of objects with "key" and "value" properties, but that would be awkward to work with.

If you need to, you can determine how many properties an object has in a couple of ways:

1. `Object.keys(obj).length` will tell you how many *own, enumerable* properties the object has (ignoring any with `Symbol` names, if you're using ES2015). The number will not include any inherited properties or any non-enumerable properties. The answer in your example would be 2.
2. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length)` will tell you how many *own* properties the object, has regardless of whether they're enumerable (but again ignoring any with `Symbol` names). The number will not include any inherited properties or any non-enumerable properties. The answer in your example would again be 2 as your object has no non-enumerable properties.

> I have tried `Object.keys(chatmessage).length` but it returns the total number key value(2) but I have only one record.

As I said above, `Object.keys` will tell you how many own enumerable *properties* the object has. If you're trying to find out how many *objects* there are, the answer is 1.

If your goal is to send an *array* of chat messages, then you want to create that like this:

```
var chatmessages = [
    {"message":"Hello", "to":"sjdfjhsdf"}
];
```

That defines an array with one entry: A single object representing a chat message. Multiple ones would be separated with `,`:

```
var chatmessages = [
    {"message":"Hello", "to":"sjdfjhsdf"},         // First message
    {"message":"Hello again", "to":"sjdfjhsdf"}    // Second message
];
```

Note that if you're doing that, your verb should probably be `listmessages` (plural), not `listmessage`. (I mention this in case your native language handles plurals differently from English; there are a *lot* of different ways plurals are handled in the various human languages around the planet. :-) )

Comment: Last sentence was funny ;) `Object.keys(OBJ)` could help!

Comment: @Rayon: LOL, I was just adding a note about `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.